# MediaRecorder - framerate decelerates to a crawl upon using new Surface from the GLSurfaceView's SurfaceTexture as the preview

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, glsurfaceview

I'm currently trying to use a `GLSurfaceView` as a preview for the `MediaRecorder to record a video`. My current extension of the `GLSurfaceView` has a `SurfaceTexture` setup as the preview of the `Camera` object to be used for my `MediaRecorder`

I decided to make a getter for the `GLSurfaceView`'s extension's `SurfaceTexture` and setup my `MediaRecorder`'s preview surface like this:

```
mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(new Surface(glSurfaceViewInstance.getSurfaceTexture()))
```

My current problem is that, for some reason, the framerate of the preview starts out normal, but slows down considerably to a crawl, possibly ending in a still image the longer I press the recording button.

Why is this, and how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a threading issue this time. My UI update Thread's code was like this:

```
public class ThreadProgress extends Thread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (progressValue < MAX_DURATION_VIDEO && !mThreadProgress.isInterrupted() && isRecording) {
                /*
                try {
                    progressValue = (int) (previousProgressInMillis + System.currentTimeMillis() - startProgressMillis);
                    Log.i("progress_val", progressValue + "");
                    Message message = new Message();
                    message.arg1 = progressValue;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
                */

                progressValue = (int) (previousProgressInMillis + System.currentTimeMillis() - startProgressMillis);
                Log.i("progress_val", progressValue + "");
                Message message = new Message();
                message.arg1 = progressValue;
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
            if (progressValue == MAX_DURATION_VIDEO) {
                try {
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the commented part instead of the one I had uncommented worked. Is it because `Thread.sleep(1)` is supposed to unclog the thread queue or something?